# Problem sending request body with axios create

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a post request using axios create and send data on the body but the body is always empty when I get It on the backend. I don't know what is wrong, I'm sending the data as required in the axios docs. I'd really appreciate if someone could give some help with this.

**This is my request function:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const request = async ({
  method,
  action,
  headers,
  data,
  callbackFunction,
  exceptionHandlerFunction,
}) => {
  const config = {
    method: method || 'get',
    baseURL: `http://localhost:3333/`,
    url: action,
    data: data || null,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      ...headers,
    },
  };

  const { data: response } = await axios
    .create(config)
    .request()
    .catch(error => {
      if (exceptionHandlerFunction) {
        exceptionHandlerFunction();
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

  if (callbackFunction) {
    callbackFunction(response);
  } else {
    alert({ message: response.meta.message });
  }
};

export default request;
```

**This is the request being made:**

```
import React from 'react';
import request from './request';

function App() {
  const makeRequest = () => {
    request({
      method: 'post',
      action: 'test/endpoint',
      data: {
        test: 'test',
      },
      callbackFunction: response => {
        console.log(response);
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => makeRequest()}>
        test
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why its empty, but from the way you set it up it looks like your data will look like this: data: { data: { tests: 'test' } } which I don't think you want (data twice)?

Comment: No, the data is just {test: 'test'}.

Comment: Your method seems soo complicated - Maybe You need a working architecture?

Comment: You can check in the [network tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/imgs/network.png) in the devtools if the request''s body is actually empty. If not, maybe the problem is in the server.

Comment: @PiotrŻak I don't know, It doesn't look so complicated to me. But according to axios docs It should work, right?

Comment: @MoshFeu I did and It's empty there too.

Comment: Maybe `data` is null somehow?